# Modulus In VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I want to ask about how modulus does not work for me.

For example:

```
 Option Explicit

 Private Function Modulus_Operator(Value1, Value2)

     Modulus_Operator = Value1 - (Int(Value1 / Value2) * Value2)

 End Function

 Private Sub Form_Activate()

     Dim A, B, BaseOut as double

     A = 67^89
     BaseOut = 35

     text1.text =  Modulus_Operator(A, BaseOut)

 End Sub
```

Comment: You can simply write `A mod BaseOut`.

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: i dont compile this code

Comment: Please let us know the error which VB6 is giving.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just to note - `Dim A, B, BaseOut as double` means actually `Dim A as variant, B as variant, BaseOut as double`.

Comment: When replying to comments with additional information, please edit your answer rather than adding another comment so it is easier to read. Second, You commented "I dont compile this code". I tried your code exactly as posted and it does compile, and returns 0. When asking for help with a problem details are important. Please add to your question the exact problem, with the text of any error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your function must return an integer. You mustn't to forget types:

```
Private Function Modulus_Operator(Value1 as integer, Value2 as integer) as integer

  Modulus_Operator = Value1 - (Int(Value1 / Value2) * Value2)

End Function
```

Anyway... do you know about mod for modulus?

Answer (score 0):

You try something 'impossible'. Do you know the range of values an integer can store? Your value 67^89 is far beyond this value, so you get an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()

 Dim A, B, BaseOut As Double

 A = 67 ^ 89
 BaseOut = 35

 Text1.Text = Modulus_Operator(Val(A), Val(BaseOut))

End Sub



Private Function Modulus_Operator(Value1 As Double, Value2 As Double) As Double

 Modulus_Operator = Value1 - (Int(Value1 / Value2) * Value2)

End Function
```